# 424 object required error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have written this so far, what I am aiming to do is to find the value ORDER31 in column D. If this condition is met I would like the find the corresponding value in the same row but from column C, in this case I have used OFFSET() and placed this value into a variable called colC. I then wish to do a lookup with this value and pull in a new value which I want to assign to newVal. I then wish to assign this newVal to the original cell where ORDER31 was found.

I get a 424 object required error, and I am not sure where I am going wrong?

```
 Sub illHack()

     Sheets("Data").Select
     Dim colC As String
     Dim newVal As String

     For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("D:D"))
         If r.Text = "ORDER31" Then
             colC = r.Offset(0, -1)
             newVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(colC, Lookup.Range("I17:K22"), 2, False)
             r.Offset(0, 0) = newVal
         End If
     Next r

     Sheets("Control-Sheet").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume you don't have a sheet in the code workbook whose **code name** (rather than tab name) is `Lookup`.

Comment: Tab name is Lookup, what do you mean by code name?

Comment: Just on a side note it might be worthwhile replacing the `ActiveSheet` and explicitly stating which sheet with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")` instead of using it based on selection - This could cause errors during the workflow. Also can you state which Line this is throwing the error - Step through the code line by line using F8. It might not like how you're stating the range or your If condition.

Comment: If the tab name is Lookup, you need to use `Sheets("Lookup").Range("I17:K22")` and not `Lookup.Range("I17:K22")`. The code name is a property you can set in the VBE for a sheet so that you can refer to it using the same name no matter what the tab shows.

Comment: newVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(colC, Lookup.Range("I17:K22"), 2, False) Is throwing the error

Comment: You need to replace the part I mentioned.

Comment: I edited the code as advised, the error has gone.

Comment: Good catch, @Rory. You should put that down as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Lookup is the tab name and not the code name, you need to use:

```
newVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(colC, Worksheets("Lookup").Range("I17:K22"), 2, False)
```